# Opencart - Notice: Undefined property: Proxy::getProducts

Tags: php, opencart

So, my site is down due to this error. The crazy thing is my site was working perfectly yesterday. The error is

Notice: Undefined property: Proxy::getProducts in /home/mybundl8/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_system_engine_action.php on line 51

**And this is what's on line 51**

$reflection = new ReflectionClass($class);

```
    if ($reflection->hasMethod($this->method) && $reflection->getMethod($this->method)->getNumberOfRequiredParameters() <= count($args)) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($controller, $this->method), $args);
    } else {
        return new \Exception('Error: Could not call ' . $this->route . '/' . $this->method . '!');
    }
}
```

}

My site is http://mybundlesboujee.com
Any advice, or what this error could possibly be would help me tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue in the Live Server. But the thing is I had loaded the module and called it correctly. But still, it didn't do any favor for me.

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
$this->model_catalog_product->addmyproducts($myproducts);

class Model**Extension**Modulename_here extends Model {
```

The solution to get around this problem was to figure out 
**How does the Architecture in OpenCart Framework works?**
**Follow the below solution:**

- Find under the Opencart directory for
  **/system/storage/modification/admin**.
   Here you'll be able to see the MVC directory
- Under the modification folder, you'll find all the codes written on to it
- You need to identify the calling part of the module in the model that has been defined or not?
- After identifying you'll come to see that function definition will not exist that's the reason.
- Further if you define the same function under  /system/storage/modification/admin/.../... you'll never see Undefined property: Proxy::module_name

### Update

Irrespective to the functions defined, if there are two functions with the same name called twice under a single file raises ambiguity in vqmod module

For Eg. Calling method `getWarehouseDetails()` if it lies under `index()` & another one in `warehousedetails()` in a single file with two different calls with two different file names while loading `$this->load->model(../..);` you'll get

> Notice: Undefined property: Proxy::getWarehouseDetails in
>   /var/www/html/bluemb/vqmod/vqcache/vq2system_storage_modification_system_engine_action.php
>   on line 51

In the below eg. getWarehouseDetails() called in index() & another one in warehousedetails()

```
$this->load->model('tool/upload');
$warehouse_details = $this->model_tool_upload->getWarehouseDetails($seller_id);

$this->load->model('catalog/information');
$this->data['warehouse_details'] = $this->model_catalog_information->getWarehouseDetails($seller['seller_id']);
```